# Per-pixel Descriptive Statistics through multiple Raster layers

Tags: qgis, python, raster, statistics

I'm looking for computing different descriptive statistics through a set of raster layers. I need to make it with a python script capable of running into a standalone tool within the QGIS. To do so first I made it by using the "Model Builder" within the QGIS and from the model I have extracted the script. I used the r.series from GRASS and it works as a model. The script is the following, for the case of the "maximum":

```
##=name

##1=raster 

##3=raster

##2=raster

##4=raster

##maximum=output raster

outputs_GRASSR.SERIES_1=processing.runalg('grass:r.series',[1,3,2,4],True,6,'-10000000000,10000000000',None,0.0,maximum)
```

Actually at this point I need to use a "multiple raster" instead of 1,2,3,4. I mean I would like to make something like:

```
##MAXIMUM=name

##RASTERS=multiple raster

##maximum=output raster

import os
import processing

lddLrs = RASTERS.split(';')
for lyr in lddLrs:
    processing.runalg('grass:r.series', RASTERS,True,6,'-10000000000,10000000000',None,0.0,maximum)
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea to solve it?

I have tried the following:

##=name

##1=multiple raster

##maximum=output raster

import processing

processing.runalg('grass:r.series', [1],True,6,None,0.0,'-10000000000,10000000000',maximum)

But it still doesn.t work. Any solution?